# wireshark extract w3c log file

Tags: log-files, url, wireshark

Does anyone know how I would go about extracting urls in w3c extended log format from a wireshark pcap capture file?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question, but Wireshark doesn't do that. It's not a log parsing tool (that I'm aware of) it's a packet capture program.

Comment: i know wireshark doesn't do that. I'm wondering how I can parse a wireshark file and output a http log file.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. How about looking at the log file on the web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not practical with Wireshark but have a look at this: http://chaosreader.sourceforge.net/

> This is a type of "any-snarf" program,
>   as it will fetch ... HTTP
>   transfersfrom the captured data inside
>   network traffic logs. A html index
>   file is created that links to ...
>   reports such as image reports and HTTP
>   GET/POST content reports.

I don't think the reports are in w3c extended log format but...why so strict? Surely a bit a perl will let you munge them into w3c extended log format.

See http://isc.sans.edu/diary.html?storyid=6961 for more leads.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I'm looking for. I've been able to convert that output into w3c logs. Thanks again!